# Is it possible to get Flux in a magnetic circuit with zero mmf?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

From an Example that I stumbled upon on A.E. Fitzgerald's book on electric Machines. He assumed that there is flux in a circuit with zero mmf. Which I find very confusing. I would appreciate it if anyone can put some insight of how it came about.

[image: Example 1.9 from A.E. Fitzgerald's electric Machines book]

Answer (score 2):

In the example, the core permeability is assumed infinite (it says it in two places). With infinite permeability comes infinite inductance and therefore any reasonable AC excitation (frequency greater than zero Hz) will not cause any current to flow hence ampere turns or MMF and H (ampere turns per metre) have to be zero.

Further down they discuss two real materials that clearly don't have infinite permeability.